# tablesorter jquery - how to fix column headers

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter, displaytag

I am using tablesorter jquery to sort the column in my table. I want to freeze my table header. Is there any way to do that using tablesorter jquery? Thanks in advance.

My tablesorter code:

```
("#rates").tablesorter({
    widgets: ['zebra'],
    widgetZebra: {
        css: ["even", "odd"]
    },
    headers: {
        0: {
            sorter: false
        },
        4: {
            sorter: false
        }
    },
    headerClass: 'header',
    sortClassAsc: 'headerSortUp',
    sortClassDesc: 'headerSortDown'
});
```

I also tried this.

```
 widgetOptions: {
      stickyHeaders : 'tablesorter-stickyHeader',
  },
```

Comment: Your code is missing `$` or `jQuery`?

Comment: *Please note* the stickyHeaders widget & `widgetOptions` only work with [this fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/), not the original from tablesorter.com; Tablesorter (either version) does not include options like `headerClass`, `sortClassAsc`, `sortClassDesc`. And lastly, the forked version moved the `widgetZebra` option into `widgetOptions` as `zebra`.

Answer (score 2):

You can add this to your tablesorter initialization:

```
$(‘table’).tablesorter({
  widgets: ['stickyHeaders']}
)
```

This would activate 1st row freezing automatically.
Make sure to remove exisitng scrolling techniques like: overflow: auto;

See my [post](http://morkrispil.wordpress.com/2013/11/04/tablesorter-stickyheaders-allowing-html-header/) about this and how to add your custom HTML header, if needed.
Please let me know if it helps :)

Comment: Please be aware that the stickyHeaders widget only works with the [forked version of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/) and not the original v2.0.5 from tablesorter.com.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to stick your table header:

```
  widgetOptions: {

      // css class name applied to the sticky header row (tr)
      stickyHeaders : 'tablesorter-stickyHeader',
  }
```

Comment: Is there any specific version of tablesorter to be used for this?

Comment: May be. I got this from the following link: http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-sticky-header.html